# WooCommerce как поменять попап на другой?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Есть два окошка, которые появляются при клике на кнопку.

Первое: При клике на кнопку "В корзину" на странице каталога (это окно добавляет плагин YITH WooCommerce Added to Cart Popup):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второе: При клике на кнопку "В корзину" в карточке товара (Стандартное окно самой темы).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача:
Убрать окно, встроенное в тему, и заменить его на окно, добавляемое плагином.

Вот что я нашёл на данный момент:
Окно, которое нужно убрать (фото #2).

```
<div class="modal fade" id="added">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h2>Добавлено в корзину!</h2>
            <a href="/cart" class="btn green_btn mt30" role="button">Перейти в корзину</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Функция, которая добавляет окно плагина (фото #1).

```
public function add_to_cart_success_ajax( $fragments ) {
  $show_image = get_option( 'yith-wacp-show-image', 'no' ) === 'yes';
  $show_price = get_option( 'yith-wacp-show-price', 'no' ) === 'yes';
  $view_cart  = get_option( 'yith-wacp-show-go-cart', 'yes' ) === 'yes';
  $continue   = get_option( 'yith-wacp-show-continue-shopping', 'yes' ) === 'yes';
  $cart_url   = wc_get_cart_url();
  $product    = isset( $_REQUEST['product_id'] ) ? wc_get_product( intval( $_REQUEST['product_id'] ) ) : false;
  // Let's filter button urls.
  $cart_url              = apply_filters( 'yith_wacp_go_cart_url', $cart_url );
  $continue_shopping_url = apply_filters( 'yith_wacp_continue_shopping_url', '#' );

  ob_start();
  ?>

  <?php if ( $product ) : ?>

    <?php if ( $show_image ) : ?>
      <div class="product-image">
        <?php echo $product->get_image(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="product-info">
      <p><?php echo '<b>' . esc_html( $product->get_title() ) . '</b> ' . esc_html__( 'Был добавлен в вашу корзину', 'yith-woocommerce-added-to-cart-popup' ); ?></p>
      <?php if ( $show_price ) : ?>
        <div class="product-price">
          <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

  <?php else : ?>

    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Added to your cart', 'yith-woocommerce-added-to-cart-popup' ); ?></p>

  <?php endif ?>

  <div class="actions">
    <?php if ( $view_cart ) : ?>
      <a class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'yith_wacp_go_cart_class', 'button go-cart' ) ); ?>"
        href="<?php echo esc_url( $cart_url ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'В корзину', 'yith-woocommerce-added-to-cart-popup' ); ?></a>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if ( $continue ) : ?>
      <a class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'yith_wacp_continue_shopping_class', 'button continue-shopping' ) ); ?>"
        href="<?php echo esc_url( $continue_shopping_url ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Продолжить покупки', 'yith-woocommerce-added-to-cart-popup' ); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <?php
  $fragments['yith_wacp_message'] = ob_get_clean();

  return $fragments;
}
```

Эта штука в том же файле, что и функция выше. Она, как я понимаю, вызывает это окно при клике.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', array( $this, 'add_to_cart_success_ajax' ), 99, 1 );
```

Это тоже в файлах плагина. Функция add_to_cart_success_ajax (см. выше) вставляет в div с классом yith-wacp-content содержимое.

```
<div id="yith-wacp-popup">
<div class="yith-wacp-overlay"></div>
<div class="yith-wacp-wrapper woocommerce">
    <div class="yith-wacp-main">
        <div class="yith-wacp-head">
            <a href="#" class="yith-wacp-close">X</a>
        </div>
        <div class="yith-wacp-content"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: UPD: Ошибка, извиняюсь. Окно, которое находится в карточке товара, добавляет плагин Ajax add to cart for WooCommerce.

Comment: "Попуп" - пуп у попа. А английское слово popup произносится и пишется по-русски как "попап".